# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML

Tags: joomla

I got this error few times in a day and my site is down, it happens from nowhere. What do I need to fix, so I dont get this error anymore?

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/templates/it_thecity/icetools/icetool.php:219 Stack trace: #0 /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/templates/it_thecity/icetools/icetool.php(219): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/templates/it_thecity/icetools/layout_vars.php(44): iceTool::getYoutubeSubscribers('icetheme') #2 /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/templates/it_thecity/index.php(29): require_once('/hosting/dfashi...') #3 /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php(531): require('/hosting/dfashi...') #4 /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php(591): JDocumentHTML->_loadTemplate('/hosting/dfashi...', 'index.php') #5 /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php(414): JDocumentHTML->_fetchTemplate(Array) #6 /hosting/dfashion/public_html/ in /hosting/dfashion/public_html/mysite/v2/templates/it_thecity/icetools/icetool.php on line 219`

Comment: When does it happen? Which joomla version?

Comment: What is the code on line 219 of mysite/v2/templates/it_thecity/icetools/icetool.php? also check your access logs to see what the page is that is being accessed at this time